# Python dictionary generation, too many variables to unpack

Tags: python, python-2.7

Trying to generate a dictionary from a list of data parsed from .csv files. Getting the error "too many values to unpack", any got any ideas on a fix?

There will be repeating keys/mutliple values to append to each key.

Im pretty new to python and programming so please if you could add a short explanation of what went wrong/how to fix.

Below the script is the data how it appears when res is printed.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import csv
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
import sys
import getopt
res = []

import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument ("infile", metavar="CSV", nargs="+", type=str, help="data file") 
args = parser.parse_args()

with open("out.csv","wb") as f:
    output = csv.writer(f) 
    for filename in args.infile:
        for line in csv.reader(open(filename)): 
            for item in line[2:]:

                #to skip empty cells
                if not item.strip():
                    continue

                item = item.split(":")
                item[1] = item[1].rstrip("%")

#               print([line[1]+item[0],item[1]])
                res.append([line[1]+item[0],item[1]])
#               output.writerow([line[1]+item[0],item[1].rstrip("%")])

pp.pprint( res )

from collections import defaultdict
initial_list = [res]

d = defaultdict(list)
pp.pprint( d )  
for k, v in initial_list:
    d[k].append(float(v))  # possibly `int(v)` ?
```

and the console

```
[   ['P1L', '2.04'],
    ['Q2R', '1.93'],
    ['V3I', '20.03'],
    ['V3M', '78.18'],
    ['V3S', '1.67'],
    ['T4L', '1.16'],
    ['T12N', '75.60'],
    ['T12S', '22.73'],
    ['K14E', '1.03'],
    ['K14R', '50.65'],
    ['I15*', '63.94'],
    ['I15V', '35.30'],
    ['G17A', '38.31'],
    ['Q18R', '38.43'],
    ['L19T', '98.62'],
    ['L24*', '2.18'],
    ['D25E', '1.87'],
    ['D25N', '2.17'],
    ['M36I', '99.76'],
    ['S37N', '97.23'],
    ['R41K', '99.03'],
    ['L63V', '99.42'],
    ['H69K', '99.30'],
    ['I72V', '5.76'],
    ['V82I', '98.70'],
    ['L89M', '98.49'],
    ['I93L', '99.64'],
    ['P4S', '99.09'],
    ['V35T', '99.26'],
    ['E36A', '98.23'],
    ['T39D', '98.78'],
    ['G45R', '3.11'],
    ['S48T', '99.70'],
    ['V60I', '99.44'],
    ['K102R', '1.04'],
    ['K103N', '99.11'],
    ['G112E', '2.77'],
    ['D123N', '8.14'],
    ['D123S', '91.12'],
    ['I132M', '1.41'],
    ['K173A', '99.55'],
    ['Q174K', '99.68'],
    ['D177E', '98.95'],
    ['G190R', '2.56'],
    ['E194K', '2.54'],
    ['T200A', '99.28'],
    ['Q207E', '98.75'],
    ['R211K', '98.77'],
    ['W212*', '3.00'],
    ['L214F', '99.25'],
    ['V245E', '99.30'],
    ['E248D', '99.58'],
    ['D250E', '99.02'],
    ['T286A', '99.70'],
    ['K287R', '1.78'],
    ['E291D', '99.22'],
    ['V292I', '98.28'],
    ['I293V', '99.58'],
    ['V317A', '28.20'],
    ['L325V', '2.40'],
    ['G335D', '98.33'],
    ['F346S', '4.42'],
    ['N348I', '3.81'],
    ['R356K', '71.43'],
    ['M357I', '20.00'],
    ['M357T', '80.00']]
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 40, in <module
    for k, v in initial_list:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrapping the result in a list:

```
initial_list = [res]
```

then try to iterate over the list:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
pp.pprint( d )  
for k, v in initial_list:
    d[k].append(float(v))  # possibly `int(v)` ?
```

You want to loop over `res` instead:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in res:
    d[k].append(float(v))
```

You can do all this *in the CSV reading loop*:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)

with open("out.csv","wb") as f:
    output = csv.writer(f) 
    for filename in args.infile:
        for line in csv.reader(open(filename)): 
            for item in line[2:]:

                #to skip empty cells
                if not item.strip():
                    continue

                key, value = item.split(":", 1)
                value = value.rstrip("%")

                d[line1[1] + key].append(float(value))
```

Comment: Thnkyou, and double thanks for the explanation, as im only a couple of weeks into my learning this really does help.